# What is the Realm native integer size? Int vs Int8, Int16, Int32

Tags: realm

**TL;DR: I'm building a data set to share between iOS and Android. Should I tweak the integer sizes to match their actual ranges, or just make everything Integer** and use `Int` in Swift and `long` in both Java and Swift?

In a typical SQL database, storing a large number of 4-byte integers would take ~4x more space than a 1-byte integer[1]. However, I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26230705/19506) that *integers are stored bit-packed* and in the [Realm Java help](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types) that *The integer types byte, short, int, and long are all mapped to the same type (long actually) within Realm*. So, reading between the lines, it seems that the on disk storage will be the same regardless of what integer sub-type I use.

So, from a pure Realm / database perspective should I just use `Int` & `long` in Swift & Java respectively?  *(I.e. leaving aside language differences, like casting, in-memory size etc.)*

If an integer field is indexed, does that make any difference to the type chosen?

*PS: Many thanks to the Realm team for their great docs and good support here on SO!*

[1] *Yes, I know it's more complicated than that.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct: the same underlying storage type is used for all integer types in Realm, and that storage type adjusts the number of bits it uses per value based on the range of values stored. For example, if you only store values in the range 0-15 then each value will use fewer bits than if you store values in the range 0-65,535. Similarly, all indexes on integer properties use a common storage type.